# How to update Postman Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates, postman

I have installed Postman on my Ubuntu through snap, but every time I open it I get a warning message that ask me to update Postman:

[image: Warning message screenshot]

In the setting there isn't any "Update" option (unlike the Windows version of Postman), so how am I suppose to update it?
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sorry you are experiencing this issue and hope the issue is solved soon. That said that screenshot is crazy. It’s just text. Can you just enter the text of the error message because that screenshot adds nothing really.

Comment: I just can't read your image. Would you post its text?

Comment: problem solved guys

Answer (score 5):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo snap switch --channel=candidate postman

sudo snap refresh postman
```

Comment: For more info about upgrades, you can check on this webpage, https://learning.postman.com/docs/administration/upgrading/

Answer (score 0):

It will update automatically, eventually.

Postman's snap channel is a little delayed compared to the regular version, but it is maintained. Just wait.

If you want to force check for updates, run `snap refresh postman`. All snaps are refreshed daily by default, so IMO there's no point in doing this manually.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved it uninstalling the snap version and downloading the native app from the Postman website.

Comment: This one cannot be updated. You'd have to always download the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Run the following commands:

1. cd ~/Downloads/
2. nano ~/.local/share/applications/postman.desktop
3. [Desktop Entry] Encoding=UTF-8 Name=Postman Exec=/usr/bin/postman Icon=/opt/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png Terminal=false [freeaccount](https://freeaccount.org/) Type=Application Categories=Development

Save the file from the with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Can you please try to [edit] and fix your formatting? Use the preview below to check how your post looks like. Also, this seems like it's just about creating a shortcut to Postman. This has nothing to do with updates.